# Android download jar/aar directly from jcenter

Tags: java, android, maven, jcenter

I'm attempting to create a aar that we can re-use code in to add Server Side Events to our android apps. We're currently using [eventsource-android](https://github.com/tylerjroach/eventsource-android) which is hosted in jcenter:

```
compile 'com.tylerjroach:eventsource:1.2.11'
```

That works if we use it in the context of the aar itself, or if I manually add that into each project.

What I'd really like to do is to download the compiled aar from jcenter and include the code with the aar we're creating wrapped in our own code. Is there any way to download the jar/aar from jcenter directly?

Comment: Good to note. Thans!

Comment: @CommonsWare You can't download anything directly from bintray now. Any work arounds?

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala "You can't download anything directly from bintray now" -- JCenter still works. It is read-only at this point, but since that project has not been updated in years, that does not seem like it will be a problem. The fact that the project has not been updated in years, though, suggests that you might want to find some alternative, if one exists.